# ga send event in Google Analytics not working

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I'm trying to set up scroll tracking by using Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics. When user scrolls to certain part of page, it activates the tag in Tag Manager then creates an Event in Google Analytics.

This is the code that someone made for doing the tracking.

http://pastebin.com/TEuW74vu

If I set the debug flag to true, the popups occur normally and works fine. If I set it to false, the requests are never triggered and the events are never made.

I visited the website it was implemented on and opened the error console and this is what I saw.

http://puu.sh/gfGC4/d34868bb02.png

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are calling the analytics.js library on the page you are setting the event tracking on, as per the standard UA tracking snippet, the ga object won't exist and will give you an error. What you should be doing is, instead of calling the ga 'send' method, do a push into the dataLayer

```
datalayer.push({
   'event': 'scrolling',
   'category': 'some category',
   'action': 'some action',
   'label': 'some label'
})
```

And then in GTM you would fire your event based on the datalayer 'event'. With custom dimensions, you would add them to the event hits configured in your tags.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid using GTM?